# Use limits with numerical cell reference in Google Sheets Query

Tags: limit, google-sheets-query

I have a query on my Google Sheet in which I use a cell reference in the 'where' condition. The formula is similar to the following example. The referred cell 'F2' contains only numerical data, hence the &F2 after the double quotes. This query statement works fine and the output is as expected.

`=query(DataRange,"select A,B,F where D>="&F2)`

However, I need just one result (the first occurrence) as output and would like to use the 'limit' function. I can't figure out how or where I should insert 'limit 1' in this query. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=query(DataRange,"select A,B,F where D>="&F2 & " limit 1 offset 0")
```

Comment: Awesome! Apologies for the dealyed response.